# Get path of project created in experimental Instance of Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-project

I am developing a Visual Studio extension package. Every time I test run, an experimental instance of VS opens up. I created a project in the experimental instance; how can I get the path of the project created in the experimental instance?

Answer (score 1):

Given the [IVsHierarchy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsHierarchy.aspx) object that represents the project hierarchy, you can use the VSITEMID_ROOT id when calling the [GetProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivshierarchy.getproperty.aspx) method with the [VSHPROPID_ProjectDir / VSHPROPID_Name properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.__vshpropid.aspx).

Alternatively, if you have an [EnvDTE.Project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.project.aspx), then you can use the [EnvDTE.Project.FullName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.project.fullname.aspx) property.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should import EnvDTE (in EnvDTE.dll). Then I declared property ProejectFullName

```
string ProejectFullName{ get; }
```

A string representing the full path and name of the project object’s file.

```
public void GetmyFilePath(DTE2 dte)

{  
    try
    {   // Open a project before running this sample.
        Project prj = dte.Solution.Projects.Item(1);
        Projects prjs;


string msg, msg2 = "Global Variables:";
    msg = "FileName: " + prj.FileName;
    msg += "\nProejectFullName: " + prj.ProejectFullName;
    msg += "\nProject-level access to " + prj.CodeModel.CodeElements.Count.ToString() +
        " CodeElements through the CodeModel";
    prjs = prj.Collection;
    msg += "\nThere are " + prjs.Count.ToString() + " projects in the same collection.";
    msg += "\nApplication containing this project: " + prj.DTE.Name;
    if (prj.Saved)
        msg += "\nThis project hasn't been modified since the last save.";
    else
        msg += "\nThis project has been modified since the last save.";
    msg += "\nProperties: ";
    foreach (Property prop in prj.Properties)
    {
        msg += "\n  " + prop.Name;
    }
    foreach (String s in (Array)prj.Globals.VariableNames)
    {
        msg2 += "\n  " + s;
    }

    MessageBox.Show(msg, "Project Name: " + prj.Name);
    MessageBox.Show(msg2);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
}
```